# yaml multiline regex

Tags: python, regex, yaml, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I would like to write a `pygrep` hook with `pre-commit` which finds cases of, e.g.

```
    .. warning:
```

(when it should be `.. warning::`).

If I write

```
-   repo: local
    -   id: incorrect-sphinx-directives
        name: Check for incorrect Sphinx directives
        language: pygrep
        entry: \.\. (autosummary|contents|currentmodule|deprecated|function|image|important|include|ipython|literalinclude|math|module|note|raw|seealso|toctree|versionadded|versionchanged|warning):[^:]
        files: \.(py|pyx|rst)$
```

then this works - however, the string is unreadably long. Is there a way to split it into multiple lines?

I tried

```
        entry: "\
            .. (autosummary|contents|currentmodule|deprecated\
            |function|image|important|include|ipython\
            |literalinclude|math|module|note|raw|seealso\
            |toctree|versionadded|versionchanged|warning\
            ):[^:]"
```

but that doesn't work (the resulting regular expression is different).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not using regex to modify yaml, not sure what you mean there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions) you can use a *verbose* expression:

```yaml
        entry: |
            (?x)^(
                thing|
                other_thing|
                other_other_thing
            )$
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning what the `|` [really does](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688). Using `>` could be viable as well.

Comment: @DaSourcerer it makes no difference for python verbose regexes which ignore external whitespace

Comment: True. It is still a feature of YAML useful to know, IMHO.

Comment: sure, but it doesn't matter for this Q&A

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to do

```
        entry: "\
            \\.\\. (autosummary|contents|currentmodule|deprecated\
            |function|image|important|include|ipython\
            |literalinclude|math|module|note|raw|seealso\
            |toctree|versionadded|versionchanged|warning\
            ):[^:]"
```